# Rails assert_equal doesn't always work with DateTimes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, minitest

I get an error in my functional test when using `assert_equal`:

```
  1) [31mFailure[0m:
test_should_allow_dealer_to_extend_offer:21
<Thu, 14 Apr 2011 23:59:59 PDT -07:00> expected but was
<Thu, 14 Apr 2011 23:59:59 PDT -07:00>.
```

Notice that the two show the same time and time zone.  I checked and they are the same class type (ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone).  So why aren't they equal?

It's a standard DateTime field in the database, which I think is only stored down to the second right?

I can get it to pass by converting them to integers or using `assert_in_delta` with a range of 1 minute.  But was just wondering.

Btw this is Rails 2.3.8 and MySQL.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm getting the same error too. It looks like this was [reported back in 2009](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/3117-timewithzone-comparison-fails-for-distinct-instances-of-same-time):

> I've seen this happen in tests before - typically caused by the database having a different time resolution than the system. So even though the two times print identically, one is really (for instance) 15:45:32.012445362 and the DB loads back 15:45:32, which doesn't compare as equal.

The suggested solution, which worked for me:

> In your tests, you can try coercing to_a before comparing; usec value isn't returned in the to_a representation: